# How does one enter a Python virtual environment and run shell commands in it from a shell script?

Tags: python, shell, virtualenv

I have been writing a shell script to be run in a CentOS 7 Docker container in order to create an AppImage. In this script I would like to run the Shell command `pip install -U spyder` from within a Python virtual environment (started by running `source AppDir/usr/bin/activate`) started by the shell script. The problem is that I don't know how to do this because lines in the script after the `source AppDir/usr/bin/activate` line are ignored (as at this point in the script, the shell has entered the Python virtual environment). So is there some option I need to pass the `source AppDir/usr/bin/activate` command so that it will run the `pip install -U spyder` command in this Python virtual environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install your requirement without activating virtual environment, but with providing full path to your virtualenv `pip`.

```
<path_to_virtualenv>/bin/pip install -U spyder
```

Because what `activate` is doing it's putting your virtualenv `bin/` folder before the `PATH`, so that `pip`, `python` commands would be references to your viartualenv's before global ones. From source of `activate`:

```
VIRTUAL_ENV="<path_to_env>"
export VIRTUAL_ENV

_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH="$PATH"
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
```

Comment: It has to be in the virtual environment as I want the installed files installed to `/AppDir/usr` (my virtualenv directory).

Comment: @BrentonHorne it will install in your virtualenv.

Comment: Cool! This takes care of pip install. But what do I do if I need to run "python install setup.py" within a virtualenv, through a shell script?

Comment: @VinayRao i believe that you just need to `<path_to_virtualenv>/bin/python install setup.py`. That's all.:)